# Dynamic Vertex Buffer Creation Failure

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am trying to create a dynamic vertex buffer, so that I can write to the buffer by using ID3D11DeviceContext::Map(). However, every time I try to create the vertex buffer it fails. This is my code. I've done this successfully in other projects, so I have no idea why what I wrote isn't working. Here is the code:

```
//create vertex buffer
    Vertex* vertices = static_cast<Vertex*>(std::malloc((4000) * sizeof(Vertex)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].pos.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.y = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.z = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.y = 0.0f;
    }
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 4000;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices; 
    HRESULT hr = Device->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &VertexBuffer );

    std::free(vertices);
```

After messing around with the code, I noticed that this code succeeded:

```
//create vertex buffer
    Vertex* vertices = static_cast<Vertex*>(std::malloc((4000) * sizeof(Vertex)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].pos.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.y = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.z = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.y = 0.0f;
    }
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 4000;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices; 
    HRESULT hr = Device->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &VertexBuffer );

    std::free(vertices);
```

This code also succeeded:

```
//create vertex buffer
    Vertex* vertices = static_cast<Vertex*>(std::malloc((4000) * sizeof(Vertex)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].pos.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.y = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].pos.z = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.x = 0.0f;
        vertices[i].tex.y = 0.0f;
    }
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 4000;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices; 
    HRESULT hr = Device->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &VertexBuffer );

    std::free(vertices);
```

It seems to only fail to create the vertex buffer when bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC and bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE at the same time. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having this problem a while ago. As MSDN says, when you create a resource as a dynamic one, you should fill it using ID3D11DeviceContext::Map(). Even if it's the first time. So when you create the buffer just try passing NULL instead of &InitData. After the buffer is created, map it and fill. As far as I rembember this solved the problem in my case. Here's the source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes that fixed it, thanks. It's strange, I've never run into that problem before.